# How do I override the default back button action in Cordova?

Tags: android, cordova, events, event-handling

I've followed the example code in the [Cordova docs](http://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/cordova/events/events.html#backbutton) to override the device back button (using ES6), but it doesn't work as expected:

```
const onBackButtonPress = () => {
  console.log('pressed');
};
document.addEventListener('backbutton', onBackButtonPress, false);
```

When I run the app on my Android device, my override code gets invoked, but the app also exits as if the default back button action is also being invoked.

**How can I prevent the app from exiting when the back button is pressed?**

I've already tried adding `e.preventDefault()` to the callback function for `addEventListener`

I'm doing this after the `deviceready` event has fired.

I'm using Cordova 7.0.1 and my platform is cordova-android 6.2.3

Comment: Hi mradbourne, did you manage to solve your issue? I got the same problem here

Comment: @Kaixin No, I didn't find a solution. Still no idea why it's not working. :(

Answer (score 1):

I have used as below:

```js
if(cordova.platformId === "android") {
  document.addEventListener("backbutton", function (event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    var confirmStatus = confirm("Do you want to exit?");
    if (confirmStatus === true) {
      navigator.app.exitApp();
    }
    }, false);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

While all answers here are correct, on some devices they still don't work. I had the same issue on Huawei P smart 2019, while everything worked correctly on Huawei MediaPad T3. In my case window focus was the problem, it was lost at some point during startup.

So as others have suggested, add this after device ready:
document.addEventListener('backbutton', () => {}, false);

In addition at some point after launch in a Java plugin (after the splash screens):
this.cordova.getActivity().getWindow().getDecorView().requestFocus();

This is also what Cordova does in CordovaActivity.onResume. If your back button works correctly after suspending and resuming the app, but not before that, this should fix your problem.

Answer (score 0):

I am using this code in my apps:

```
document.addEventListener("backbutton", function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    return;
}, false);
```

Note, to run this code when [device is ready](https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/4.0.0/cordova/events/events.deviceready.html)

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion - I'm doing this after the `deviceready` event has fired.

Comment: And still not working? Maybe try delete and add one more time android platform in cordova. Sometimes this helps.

Comment: I tried deleting platforms and doing a `cordova prepare` to re-add the correct platform versions. It didn't work unfortunately.

Answer (score 0):

For those of you that are using React, you may want to override the back button behaviour *inside a component*. If you have a changing function to navigate back, it can be a bit challenging, since React rerenderings can produce undesired consequences.

This is the code I use for this situation:

```
function MyComponent(): JSX.Element {
    // ...

    useEffect(() => {
        const handleDeviceBackButton = (event: Event) => {
            event.preventDefault();
            navigateBack();
        };

        document.addEventListener("backbutton", handleDeviceBackButton);

        return () => {
            document.removeEventListener("backbutton", handleDeviceBackButton);
        };
    }, [navigateBack]);

    // ...
}
```

React [documentation](https://react.dev/reference/react/useEffect#parameters) says:

> Your setup function may also optionally return a *cleanup function*.

If we use the cleanup function to remove the listener, we avoid undesired repetitions.